# Button does not respond for the first click

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have the page for user to enter the personal phone number. When the TextBox got focus the virtual keyboard is shown, but then when a user finish typing the phone number and click the "Next" green button (Sorry about Russian language on screenshot) the first click "goes through" the button and close the keyboard and only the next click activate the click event. 
Any ideas how to fix that? 
Maybe there are some problems with page focus state, but I honestly don't know.

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
This is XAML of my page

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource GeneralAppBackground}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    // Control to show the loading state
    <controls:LoadingPageState x:Name="LoadingGrid" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.RowSpan="3" Canvas.ZIndex="1" TitleOfOperation="Проверка существования кошелька..." />
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GeneralAppHeaderStyle}">
        <TextBlock Text="Введите номер телефона" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,20,0">
            <TextBlock x:Uid="Greeting" Foreground="#979797" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" PlaceholderText="+7" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="#979797" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,10,0" Template="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="UserPhoneNumberInput" Grid.Column="1" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" PlaceholderText="777 123 12 12" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="#979797" MaxLength="10" Background="Transparent" InputScope="TelephoneNumber" Template="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}" TextChanged="UserPhoneNumberInput_TextChanged" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="HintText" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Foreground="#979797" TextAlignment="Center">
                Ваш телефон будет использоваться в качестве номера кошелька
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="NextStepButton" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False" Content="Далее" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource WideGreenButtonStyle}" Click="NextStepButton_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And here is my C# code for button click event

```
private void NextStepButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!UserPhoneNumberInput.Text.All(Char.IsDigit) || UserPhoneNumberInput.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            NotifyUser.ShowWrongPhoneNumberFormatMessage();
            return;
        }

        phoneNumber = Helpers.FormatNumber(UserPhoneNumberInput.Text);

        // Activate the ContentLoading ring
        LoadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        LoadingGrid.IsProgressRingActive = true;

        CheckNumber(phoneNumber);
    }
```

And here, if it is important the XAML of my "LoadingGrid"

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#CC000000">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRing" Width="50" Height="50" Foreground="White" IsActive="{x:Bind IsProgressRingActive, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="OperationTitle" Text="{x:Bind TitleOfOperation, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: seems unclear until you post your code.

Comment: @Rakitić I have updated my question with my code.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I think that this is not the case, because sometimes the button click works correctly. Most likely this is a problem in my code, but I do not know where it could be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's by design.

When you click your *NextStepButton* button, the *UserPhoneNumberInput* TextBox loses its focus and then the keyboard disappears automatically. Most likely, but depending on your custom layout templates, the *NextStepButton* just slightly moves down as well. And when you release your mouse button (assuming you're using an emulator), the *NextStepButton* is not there at that moment. That's why it does not trigger the *Click* event. As you know, the default *ClickMode* for buttons is *ClickMode.Release*. I had the exact same issue recently.

You can try adding **IsTabStop="False"** to your button properties to work around this behavior.

Comment: thank you very much for your clear explanation! Your answer helped me a lot.